# Jenkins - unable to delete builds from build history

Tags: jenkins

I was deleting some old builds from the build history in Jenkins. I was successful in deleting some. But all of a sudden I got a "Status Code: 500 Exception:Stacktrace:
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete xx/builds/.2012-03-02_15-45-42/.nfs00000000000ac05d0002d96b"

Why would this happen? How do I delete these builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Jenkins build files are stored on a network file system which has snapshotting enabled.  I ran into this problem on my Jenkins installation too; you should find that the job was either actually deleted successfully despite the error, or that you can retry the deletion and it will work the second time.

I'd recommend that you disable snapshotting and using some other method such as a regular rsync to back up your Jenkins build files.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with deleting the latest build.
I just restarted jenkins: "jenkins_url"/restart

and it helped.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 1):

> Why would this happen?

Looks like an [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) problem.

> How do I delete these builds?

I'd try deleting it again.